# How to handle a table without entity on symfony2?

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

Is it possible to handle a table without doctrine or without creating entity?
I have an existant database with many tables and i want to handle some tables but without generating etities for it!

Thanks

Comment: What-s the point? You can still use PDO or whatever you like ^^

Answer (score 3):

You can access the connection to your database through the Doctrine Entity manager, assuming you have already set up Doctrine to manage some other stuff, by using EntityManager->getConnection(), it has a method executeQuery() to just throw a query against the database.

It'll save you having to set up an extra database connection. If you are not using Doctrine at all, you can just use PDO or whatever other kind of connection you like, but you'll have to set it up yourself.